# Will SELECT become slower if I include a second non-indexed column in the query?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-performance

Let's say I have the following table:

Table **Test:**

```
ID | Name | Ver | Col3| Col4 | ... 
01 | ABC  |   2 | xxx | yyy  | ...
02 | DEF  |   8 | xxx | yyy  | ...
03 | DEF  |   8 | xxx | yyy  | ...
...
```

The `ID` column is **primary key**, **unique key**, and **clustered index** `Ver` column is nothing special.

So far I had **SELECT** queries in the following way:

```
SELECT (NAME, Col1, Col2) WHERE ID = '01'
```

The next version will contain **SELECT** queries in the following way:

```
SELECT (NAME, Col1, Col2) WHERE ID = '01' AND Ver = '8'
```

---

Why? Because I am planning to include this query in the **UPDATE** and **DELETE** queries in the system, which would make sure that there will be no concurrent editing conflicts, since it can only update where `ID` and `Ver` is matching, if the entity changed in the meantime, the **SELECT** part will defend the entity from update, since it will return nothing. (nothing to update or delete)

---

## The question

Is this change going to affect my DBs performance, or it is not going to bother about the `Ver` column in the query, since one of the columns in the select is a **unique primary key**.

If it is going to affect performance of record retrieval, should I include the `Ver` together with `ID` in a **clustered index**? Should `Ver` be a second index?

Facts and opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to try it and look at the query plan to make sure but my feeling is:

Ver does not need to be in an index. When SQL Server generates the plan it's smart enough to see that ID is unique. It will therefore get the record with `ID = '1'` and then filter that single record by `Ver = '8'`. As this part is only acting on zero or one records it doesn't need an index.

Comment: Note that filtering  by `Ver = '8'` will not affect perfomanse because index on ID column is clustered and therefore stores values of all columns. If index on ID was non-clustered it could produce additional key lookup

Comment: Sounds good. Any credible and/or official sources stating this? Thanks!

Comment: @DDan, you could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described to confirm that the clustered index stores the data rows. To learn why that means no extra lookup is required you need to learn about covering indexes, but I can't find an official source for them.